# Drag and Drop Files Copy Fails

Tags: nautilus

In Ubuntu 15.10, when I used the Files program to copy files, I could select files, drag them over a sidebar folder and the folder would automatically open so that I could continue dragging to subfolders.

Because of problems related to Ubuntu failing to recognize my graphics card I was forced to reinstall Ubuntu and went with installing 16.04.

Unfortunately now when I drag files and hover over a sidebar folder, the Files program just sits there and does nothing.

My question is how do I get the Files program in 16.04 to work the same way as it did in 15.10?

Comment: I'm always afraid when I drag the files they'll get moved and not copied. What I do is highlight the files, right click and select `Copy`. Then I navigate the folder I want them in, right click and select `Paste`. Hope this helps until you find out how to `drag` them.

Comment: Hi, the technique you recommend is one I use at times. But what leaves me scratching my head is why the program's behavior changed between the original install and the 16.04 install.  After all, that is a rather fundamental behavior.